# GDB + Rust, how to print a std::path::Path function call

Tags: rust, gdb

I want to print the result of a calling a function of a `std::path::Path` instance.

I'm using Rust 1.43 and GDB 9.1

main.rs

```rust
use std::path::Path;

fn main() {
    let path = Path::new("/home/sweet/home");
    println!("The path: {}", path.display());
}
```

When I try to debug it with rust-gdb I get this:

```
$ rust-gdb target/debug/poc-gdb-pathbuf
...
>>> start
>>> n
>>> print path
$1 = (*mut std::path::Path) 0x55555557c000
>>> print &path
$2 = (*mut *mut std::path::Path) 0x7fffffffe0c0
>>> print *path
$3 = std::path::Path {
  inner: std::ffi::os_str::OsStr {
    inner: std::sys_common::os_str_bytes::Slice {
      inner: 0x55555557c000
    }
  }
}
>>> print *path.is_absolute()
Could not find function named 'std::path::Path::is_absolute'
>>> print path.is_absolute()
Could not find function named 'std::path::Path::is_absolute'
>>> print path.display()
Function 'std::path::Path::display' takes no arguments
>>> print *path.display()
Function 'std::path::Path::display' takes no arguments
```

As you can see I cannot manage to call a single `Path` instance function correctly, either it tells me the function doesn't exists ([it does](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.is_absolute)) or that it takes no arguments (I haven't passed any).

I have no problems with a simple, minimal struct function call, here's an example that works.

main.rs

```rust
struct Something {
    x: u8
}

impl Something {
    pub fn new(x: u8) -> Self {
        Something { x }
    }

    pub fn show(&self) -> u8 {
        return self.x
    }
}

fn main() {
    let something = Something::new(10);
    something.show();
}
```

The rust-gdb session:

```
$ rust-gdb target/debug/poc-gdb-something
...
>>> start
>>> n
>>> print something
$1 = poc_gdb_pathbuf::Something {
  x: 10
}
>>> print something.show()
$2 = 10
```

I suspect it may be something about the `Path` instance being a pointer but dereferencing it doesn't help...

Why the `Path` calls doesn't work? What am I missing?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.dbg.html

Answer (score 5):

The Rust compiler does not emit complete debugging information describing everything it emits.  This, ultimately, is what hampers gdb's ability to do these things.

gdb can't make calls via traits, because traits aren't described.  There is a [Rust bug](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/1563) for this.

Printing a `Path` is likewise difficult because the Rust compiler doesn't emit debug information for dynamically sized types.  I was reluctant to hack this into gdb directly; in this case one could write custom Python code to decode these objects, by making (perhaps invalid) assumptions about their layout.  For this case, see [this Rust bug](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/43334).

Comment: I was afraid this were going to be the real answer, thank you. I'll left the question opened just in case someday the problem is solved and/or more information can be added to it.